# Max() returning second highest number...?

Tags: php, foreach, max

In my code below, print_r($vu_array) returns:

```
Array ( [0] => 249.99 [1] => 10.99 [2] => 29.99 [3] => 11.99 [4] => 10.99 )
```

but max($vu_array) returns 29.99 and **NOT** 249.99! What evil sorcery is going on here....?

```
    $vu_link = get_field('shop_link');

    $ch3 = curl_init($vu_link);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $cl3 = curl_exec($ch3);

    $dom3 = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom3->loadHTML($cl3);
    $xpath3 = new DOMXpath($dom3);

    $price3 = $xpath3->query("//p[@class='special-price']/span[@class='price']");

    foreach($price3 as $value) {
      $vu_array[] =  str_replace('$', '', $value->nodeValue);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

var_dump($vu_array) returns:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(43) " 249.99 " [1]=> string(42) " 10.99 " [2]=> string(42) " 29.99 " [3]=> string(42) " 11.99 " [4]=> string(42) " 10.99 " }
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($vu_array)` list each entry as, string or what?

Comment: Works fine for me! Please show us how you use `max()`

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm using max() as in: echo max($vu_array);

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone for your answers - SUPER quick!! I wish I could mark them all as the correct one. You guys rock :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing lexical (string) comparisons. Try changing the line inside your loop to:

```
$vu_array[] = floatval(str_replace('$', '', $value->nodeValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces in your array, so this should work:

```
<?php

    $vu_array = array(" 249.99 ", " 10.99 ", " 29.99 ", " 11.99 ", " 10.99 ");
    $vu_array = array_map("trim", $vu_array);
    echo max($vu_array);

?>
```

Output:

```
249.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *input array* is holding **string values**. If you want the `max()` function to work correctly your array should contain `float`-values.

Here I made a small example code of how to get the **max-value** by your given input array.

```
$string_arr = array( ' 249.99 ', ' 10.99 ', ' 29.99 ', ' 11.99 ', ' 10.99 ' );

$int_arr = array_map('floatval', $string_arr ); //converts all values from string to float

$biggest = max( $int_arr );

var_dump($biggest); //outputs 249.99
```